# How to trim trailing 0 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to trim trailing '0's from numbers such as 0.50, 0.40 etc. Any suggestions? Unable to use `TRIM` function in SQL Server.

I don't want to use `convert(decimal(10, 1), number)` since that will affect values such as '0.23' for ex.

Comment: This is something which is usually handled in your presentation layer.  I attempted an answer below, which covers your immediate question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic approach which should remove all trailing zeroes from any number.  First, we cast the number to text, and count how many trailing zeroes are there, using `REVERSE()`, `REPLACE()`, and `CHARINDEX()`.  Then, we use `LEFT()` to take the entire number text minus how many trailing zeroes were found.

```
SELECT LEFT(CAST(col AS VARCHAR),
            LEN(CAST(col AS VARCHAR)) -
            CHARINDEX(LEFT(REPLACE(REVERSE(CAST(col AS VARCHAR)), '0', ''), 1),
                      REVERSE(CAST(col AS VARCHAR))) +
            CHARINDEX(LEFT(REPLACE(REVERSE(CAST(col AS VARCHAR)), '0', ''), 1),
                      REPLACE(REVERSE(CAST(col AS VARCHAR)), '0', ''))) AS new_col
FROM yourTable
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

U can try this script :

`select convert (DOUBLE PRECISION , column_name) from table_name`